# Quadratic form equals zero

Tags: calculus, matrices, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

We have a quadratic form $x^TAx$ where $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ and $A$ is an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix.

Define M to be the set:

$$M=\{x \in \mathbb R^n| x^TAx=0\}$$

and a differentiable function, $\gamma$, s.t. $\gamma (t) \in M $ and $\gamma(0)=0$ we will find that $\gamma(t)^TA\gamma(t)=0$

Is it then the case that $\gamma'(t)^TA\gamma'(t)=0$ also? I believe that it should, but I don't know how to show it. Or rather (as apparently this isn't the case) that $\gamma'(0)^TA\gamma'(0)=0$?

Comment: I don't think that $\gamma'(t)^T A \gamma'(t) = 0$ should hold in general (though I don't have time to cook up a counter example now). The fact that $\gamma(t)^T A \gamma(t) = 0$ for all $t$ implies, via the product rule, that $\gamma'(t)^T A \gamma(t) + \gamma(t)^T A \gamma'(t) = 0$, though.

Answer (score 3):

If $\gamma$ is twice differentiable in 0, you have $$0=\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}\bigg\vert_{0} \gamma(t)^{T} A \gamma(t)=2( \gamma''(0)^{T}A\underbrace{\gamma(0)}_{=0}+ \gamma'(0)^{T}A\gamma'(0))=2 \gamma'(0)^{T}A\gamma'(0). $$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample for the general result. Let $A$ be the $3\times 3$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $1,1,$ and $-1$ so that $M$ is the cone $\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2=z^2\}$.

Consider a curve that spirals around the cone while moving up vertically at a constant rate: $$\gamma(t)=(t\cos(t),t\sin(t),t)$$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Its derivative  $$\gamma^\prime(t)=(\cos(t)-t\sin(t),\sin(t)+t\cos(t),1)$$  lies in $M$ if and only if $t=0$.